# Wordpress Shortcode PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I'm trying to create a basic short code in Wordpress that will allow me to run PHP on pages. This is what I have so far, but it isn't working. Advice?

The idea is it will be [php] Insert PHP here [/php']

```
<?php
function php_shortcode( $attr, $content = null ) {
    return '<?php' . $content . '?>';
}
add_shortcode('php', 'php_shortcode');
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to execute that code?  If so that doesn't really jive with shortcodes.

Comment: You'd have to `eval($content)` but you might be opening yourself up for exploitation.

Comment: Are you fully aware of the security issues with what you are trying to do? I have essentially tried the ideas of mpen and @digout. Although correct in principle there are significant problems because of the way WordPress does 'the_content' filters. I think I have the workaround but I will not proceed unless you are still interested after considering the security issues.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say you are exploring a concept that simply cannot yield success. The PHP that renders the shortcode, cannot "also" render code within itself.

Comment: Looks like he needs javascript instead to me...?

Comment: I down voted this answer because your reasoning is incorrect. I actually have implemented this and it does work. Aside from the security issues it has additional problems because of how WordPress parses the content. But, the concept itself is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Short codes as standard will filter PHP tags. You can however write php directly into the content editor. Without giving you all the advisories why it's not recommended, you can do something like the following which will allow you to write php into the content editor:

```
// write '<?php ... ?>' into the editor 

add_filter('the_content', 'allow_php', 9);

function allow_php($content) {
    if (strpos($content, '<' . '?') !== false) {
        ob_start();
        eval('?' . '>' . $content);
        $content = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: 'You can however write php directly into the content editor.' - is this really true?

Comment: I did not read your answer carefully the first time and did not notice you were using a 'the_content' filter and incorrectly tried to use a shortcode which does not work correctly in many cases. I also eventually changed my implementation to a 'the_content' filter but realized that this was an obvious thing that somebody would have written a plugin for and I found it.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this for a little while I realized there is an obvious solution. So, someone probably has written a plugin to do it and someone has - https://wordpress.org/plugins/inline-php/.

It consists of about 40 lines of PHP. The critical implementation trick is it is not done as a shortcode but as a 'the_content' filter.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'inline_php', 0);
```

This is done before other 'the_content' filter processing and avoids all the problems that I encountered trying to use it as a shortcode. Of course, there is still a significant security risk.